# Add context menu item to children of directory

Tags: windows, windows-7

Is it possible to add a context menu item to the folders of a certain directory?

The user needs to be able to run a powershell script on a directory via a right click. However, the menu item only needs to exist for the children of one specific directory.

Please advise.

Comment: This may be a better question for the developer community at StackOverflow. I'm thinking you would have to develop a custom executable that was always included in an explorer context menu, but only showed it's menu item when the path matched what it expected (ie, the directory you care about).